# Почему not in не работает в моем коде? Я пытался разбивать конструкция на два not in для '@' и для '.' , но условие не проходит. Что нужно сделать?

Tags: python

```
string = 'Ван dsytz@ru 62'

split_string = string.split(' ')

if '@' and '.' not in list(split_string[1]):
    raise NotEmailError('Некорректный email')
```

---

```
string = 'Ван dsytz@ru 62'

split_string = string.split(' ')

if '@' not in list(split_string[1]) and '.' not in list(split_string[1]):
    raise NotEmailError('Некорректный email')
```

Comment: `'@' not in split_string[1] or '.' not in split_string[1]`.

Comment: Это не работает

Comment: Достаньте материалы по булевой логике и синтаксису логических выражений в Python. От сердца на языках программирования не пишут.

Comment: Вы правы, поторопился

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
if '@' not in split_string[1] or '.' not in split_string[1]:
    raise NotEmailError('Некорректный email')
```

Условие `'@' and '.' not in list(split_string[1])` это проверка:

- `'@'` - проверка строки `'@'` - это всегда будет `True`, т.к. булевое `True` для строки - что она не пустая
- `'.' not in list(split_string[1])` - а тут уже зависит от значения в `split_string[1]`

Поэтому, нужно явно писать `'@' not in split_string[1]`, чтобы проверить наличие `'@'`. А приведение к списку в `list(split_string[1])` лишнее - оператор `in` есть и у строк

Comment: Это не работает

Comment: `and` -> `or` .

Comment: Нужно сделать проверку отсутствия обоих символов.

Comment: правильно, if '@' not in split_string[1] or '.' not in split_string[1]: raise NotEmailError('Некорректный email') вызовет NotEmailError, если в строке не содержит одновременно @ и . символа.

Comment: Спасибо всем!!!